# How to move HTML form to WP Theme

Tags: forms

:) Hi good people :)

I have a beautiful layout of advanced form in html5. There's some JS scripts and CSS with flex box. What's the easiest way to add this form into WP theme? I try with CF7 but there's some issues, I should rearrange code and CSS specially for CF7 and I want to avoid that... any suggestions?

Thank you all!

Comment: You can do it with just `php` code. Setup a `form.php` file and put all your form cord there, in your `form.php` or in the `function.php` you can handle the form submission... eg. check if the form was submited, do  validations and if it's all set, you can use `wp_mail()` to send the form. And you can insert this form in any page you want.

Comment: Thank you :) Did you know any worthy tutorial for that? It's new for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function to load your required javascript and css files for the form. Then follow this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/) to have knowledge about creating a form plugin and how to use that.

You have another option left. If you are familiar with WordPress page template then you can create a page template for the page that contains the form. Read more about [page template from here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Comment: Thank U! This tutorial help me a lot. But I have one question: is there any way to send mails without page reolading? :)

Comment: Yes there is. Please do study on  [wp.ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))